# What is the appropriate value for the ExtAudioFileWrite inNumberFrames parameter?

Tags: macos, core-audio, lossless-compression, flac

I'm working on a FLAC-to-ALAC transcoder and trying to use ExtAudioFile to write to ALAC. I am using the FLAC library's callback-based system to read in the FLAC file, which means that every frame in the FLAC file results in a function call. Within that call, I set up my buffers and call the ExtAudioFileWrite code as follows:

```
AudioBufferList * fillBufList;
fillBufList = malloc(sizeof *fillBufList + (frame->header.channels - 1) * sizeof fillBufList->mBuffers[0]);
fillBufList->mNumberBuffers = frame->header.channels;

for (int i = 0; i < fillBufList->mNumberBuffers; i++) {
    fillBufList->mBuffers[i].mNumberChannels = 1; // non-interleaved
    fillBufList->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize = frame->header.blocksize * frame->header.bits_per_sample / 8;
    fillBufList->mBuffers[i].mData = (void *)(buffer[i]);
    NSLog(@"%i", fillBufList->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize);
}

OSStatus err = ExtAudioFileWrite (outFile, 1, fillBufList);
```

Now, the number 1 in the final line is something of a magic number that I've chosen because I figured that one frame in the FLAC file would probably correspond to one frame in the corresponding ALAC file, but this seems not to be the case. Every call to ExtAudioFileWrite returns an error value of -50 (error in user parameter list). The obvious culprit is the value I'm providing for the frame parameter.

So I ask, then, what value should I be providing?

Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

(Side note: I suspected that, despite the param-related error value, the true problem could be the buffer setup, so I tried mallocing a zeroed-out dummy buffer just to see what would happen. Same error.)

Comment: On further reflection and research, it seems that the term "frame" might mean very different things in the FLAC documentation and in CoreAudio. I've tried providing the number of samples per channel, (frame->header.blocksize) but I'm still getting that parameter error.

Answer (score 2):

For ExtAudioFileWrite, the number of frames is equal to the number of samples you want to write. If you're working with 32-bit float interleaved data, it would be the mDataByteSize / (sizeof(Float32) / mNumberChannels). It shouldn't be 1 unless you meant to write only one sample, and if you're writing a compressed format, it expects a certain number of samples, I think. It's also possible that the -50 error is another issue.

One thing to check is that ExtAudioFile expects only one buffer. So your fillBufList->mNumberBuffers should always equal 1, and if you need to do stereo, you need to interleave the audio data, so that mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels is equal to 2 for stereo.

Comment: I believe that last issue you've brought up is exactly the problem; I need to use only one buffer in the fillBufList. But this brings up a sub-question: why would they use a "fillBufList" structure when mNumberBuffers is _always_ supposed to be equal to one? Why not just have the ExtAudioFileWrite function simply accept a raw buffer?

Comment: I don't know why Apple made it that way, but my experience is that having non-interleaved stereo audio data (that is, mNumberBuffers is 2, and there are two mBuffers with audio data) has never worked. Only interleaved audio data works. They might have wanted to be able to use the AudioBufferList structure elsewhere in the API for multiple buffers, but for the ExtAudioFile API, it's not used that way.